# How can I use environmental variables in the .releaserc.json?

Tags: configuration, environment-variables, semantic-release

I want to do something like this,

```
["@semantic-release/exec", {
  "prepareCmd": "echo hello ${HOME};"
}],
```

And then run this CI job with an environmental variable? Is there a method of making this work in semantic-release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use `.releaserc.js`, or `release.config.js`

You can rename the `releaserc.json` to `release.config.js` or .releaserc.js`, and then it's just a CommonJS module,

```js
const greets = "HELLO ";

module.exports = {
    "foo": `${greets} ${process.title}`
}
```

That will run as expected.

Internally semantic-release uses [`cosmiconfig`](https://github.com/davidtheclark/cosmiconfig)